# Can anyone suggest comparison criteria for various algorithms like ACO, ABC, PSO, BFO, FA, SSO,etc?

Tags: matlab, data-mining, particle-swarm, ant-colony, objective-function

I want to compare these methods using matlab. So what can be the criteria for calculating the best method, although different methods are useful as per the applications. Can I use the the objective functions described in link below. Further which function can be more useful for calculating.

http://www.geatbx.com/download/GEATbx_ObjFunExpl_v37.pdf